# Url Helper does not create a usable url

Tags: craft3, control-panel, url

When I create a cpUrl like that:

`UrlHelper::cpUrl($this->entry->cpEditUrl)`

I get something like that:

`https://hegi.test/admin/entries/article/7707-test`

But that don't work inside of the browser.
I get an 404 Error:

`HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException Entry not found`

Do I miss something?

Thanks in advance.
Michael

Comment: Is it a draft entry? I think [this](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/cefde5ca50bd99a2d13b260bbb6f616e54ec5596/src/helpers/Cp.php#L333) is how Craft is doing it?

Comment: It is not a draft entry. I have not a draftId or a revisionId on the Entry. But why. I just saved it. And this user has no permissions to publish an entry - so it has to be a draft.